# Redshift Copy command fails due '\' present in some of the data in my csv file

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy csv file from S3 to Redshift table. I have few of the columns present in my csv file that contains '\' in the data. Below is the sample data:

```
columnA|columnB|columnC|columnD|columnE 
-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
   abc |  12\ |   xyz |  test | hello 
   lmn |   123 | pqr\ |  test |   bye 
   jkl |   124 |   deg |  test |    hi
```

I am using below command to copy in Redhisft, but it fails:

```
COPY redshif_schema.redshift_table_name from 's3://bucket/folder/inputfile.csv' access_key_id '<access_id>' secret_access_key '<secret_key>' fillrecord escape delimiter as '|' IGNOREHEADER as 1 ACCEPTANYDATE emptyasnull blanksasnull maxerror 0 ;
```

When I check raw_line in stl_load_errors table, I see below (2 back slashes):

```
   abc |  12\\ |   xyz |  test | hello
```

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `ESCAPE` parameter in your `COPY` command, the [AWS COPY examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html) mention:

> The following example shows how to load characters that match the delimiter character (in this case, the pipe character). In the input file, make sure that all of the pipe characters (|) that you want to load are escaped with the backslash character (). Then load the file with the ESCAPE parameter.

This leads to `12\|xyz` being interpreted as one column as you are escaping the pipe. I guess you could run it without ESCAPE - but then it will fail if you really have `|` in a column.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I remove ESCAPE from the command, it fails as well. I want to somehow let the command know to treat "\" as a column value. How do I do that?

Comment: If I remove ESCAPE, it will try to add record number 2 in columnC as pqr\test. And it will try to add record number 2 in columnD as bye. Thus, I will have inconsistent data

Comment: Wait, it does `pqr\test` as column C, but row 1 with `12\|xyz` is fine? or is this as well in one column?

Comment: Same problem with that as well. It does similar thing to record 1 as well where the value of columnB is taken as 12\xyz

Comment: The edit of the question now shows different data, now your example input also has two backslashes, is this correct?

Comment: I actually think the easiest would be to reprocess the CSV and add quotes to the fields and then COPY the data with REMOVEQUOTES and without ESCAPE.

Comment: I dont know how it was edited wit 2 slashes. 
But your suggestion helped. There was some crlf line characters present in my text file, which was causing the issue. I fixed the file and removed ESCAPE from Redshift Copy command and it works now. Thanks a lot @Philip!!